# Accessed a dictionary with same key name but got the wrong answer

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
dic = {1:0}

def put(dic, key):
    for key in dic.keys():
        dic[key] -= 1   
    dic[key] = 0
put(dic,2)

print(dic)
```

the output is:
`{1: 0}`

However, I expected to get the result of `{1: -1}, {2: 0}`

I think the line `dic[key]` is not in the same scope as previous lines, but seems that the two lines above have an effect on the following line.

Comment: You get the result: `{1: 0}` because the last line in `put()` is: `dic[key] = 0`. The rest of the code in the function is redundant at this stage. Why do you think you should end up with two entries in `dic`?

Comment: The `key` in `for key` shadows the function's argument `key`

Comment: Where do you use `value`? It won't be possible to get `{2:2}` without value even if you followed the above comments btw

Comment: I see you have changed your code and expectations. It still seems that the `value` parameter is ignored. Did you mean that?

Comment: what is the purpose of ```value``` argument ?

Comment: @quamrana Yeah it's a mistake I'll edit it later. I want to get `{1: -1}` after the for loop, and next add a new `key` whose value is 2. I thought the parameter in `for loop` can have the same name with the function's parameter.

Comment: Ok, so the answer from @FLAW seems to be what you want. You should accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
dic = {1:0}

def put(dic, key, value):
    for _key in dic:
        dic[_key]-=1
    dic[key]=value
put(dic,2,0)

print(dic)
```

you use `key` in `for` that overrides the argument `key`